# React chat app messages don't have different className

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, channel, django-channels

I am making a chat app with django channels and react. I save the messages in state. When a new message is made I want it to have the className of the current user.

The problem is that all messages have the className of the user reading them even if they were written from other. For example I am sending messages from 2 different browsers. The one is logged as `first` and the other as `second`. If first sends a message it will appear with a className of `first`. But for `second` this message will appear with a className of `second`

```
chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
     if (ran == true) {
       const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
       setMessages(old => [...old, <p ref={oneRef} id={currentUser[0]?.username} className={currentUser[0]?.username}>{data.message}</p>])
                
    }
}
```

What can I do to solve this.

Comment: Don't use `className`, use a data attribute instead e.g. `data-username`. Class names should only be used for grouping or styling like-elements. Do not abuse it. Also, I would refrain from using an ID, because they should be unique. If you have a list of messages all by the same user, they will have the same id.

Comment: Yeah but this doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `currentUser`, use the username that comes with the payload (assuming it's available):

Also, I would avoid abusing `className` and use a data attribute i.e. `data-username` instead.

```js
chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
  if (ran == true) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    setMessages(old => [
      ...old,
      <p
        ref={oneRef}
        data-username={data.username}
      >
        {data.message}
      </p>
    ])
  }
};
```

If you need to add in CSS, you can use:

```css
[data-username="admin"]{
   /* Custom rules for user "admin"... */
}
```